# how to set a Scene in DALI Protocol with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, embedded, microcontroller, hardware, dali

I want to set DALI scene with Arduino uno. but I don't know which command should be sent?

which command should be sent twice?

and Which command should be sent first?

Answer (score 0):

According with DALI communication protocol, your frame should be like this:

```
frame[0] = 0x83;
frame[1] = 0x00;
frame[2] = ....; // DALI device id
frame[3] = ....; // 10 + scene number
frame[4] = frame[1] ^ frame[2] ^ frame[3] ^ frame[4]; // Checksum
```

It is just one command, 5 Bytes total.